# Speech recognition in .NET not working

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

i was working with a simple speech recognition application for controlling relays through a parallel port and this is the basic program how it is supposed to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

namespace speechHardware
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine instance.
          var  sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
          SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
          Console.WriteLine("starting recognizer.......");
          s.Speak("starting recognizer.");

          // Create a simple grammar that recognizes "light on", "light off", or "fan on","fan off".
            Choices colors = new Choices();
            Console.WriteLine("option list.......");
            colors.Add("light on");
            colors.Add("light off");
            colors.Add("fan on");
            colors.Add("fan off");

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(colors);
            Console.WriteLine("starting grammer builder.......");

            // Create the actual Grammar instance, and then load it into the speech recognizer.
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);

            // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
            sre.SpeechRecognized += SreSpeechRecognized;
            //sre.SetInputToWaveFile("C:\Users\Raghavendra\Documents\MATLAB\test.wav");
          sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            Console.WriteLine("input device recognised.......");         
            s.Speak("input device recognised.");
         sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("stopping recognizer.....");
            sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();

        }
        static void SreSpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            Console.WriteLine("\nSpeech Recognized: \t{0}" + e.Result.Confidence, e.Result.Text);

            if (e.Result.Confidence < 0.85)
                return;

            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "light on":
                    light(1);                    
                    s.Speak("the light has been turned on.");
                    break;
                case "light off":
                    light(0);
                    s.Speak("the light has been turned off.");
                    break;
                case "fan on":
                    fan(1);
                    s.Speak("the fan has been turned on.");
                    break;
                case "fan off":
                    fan(0);
                    s.Speak("the fan has been turned off.");
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
        }
        static void light(int val)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSpeech Recognized:light ");
        }

        static void fan(int val)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSpeech Recognized: fan");
        }


    }
}
```

This works perfectly on my friends computer but in my computer  it doesn't recognize what i speak, maybe it is not getting the input. we both have the almost the same config. the microphone is also working well and i dont know whats wrong.

i have installed 
   Microsoft Speech Platform - Software Development Kit (SDK), version 10.2 (x86 edition)
   Microsoft Speech Platform – Server Runtime, version 10.2 (x86 edition)

Please Help me out.

Comment: Try logging the confidence values. See what it outputs.

Comment: "we both have the almost the same config". What's different? If you can make the configurations the same and see if the problem goes away. When you know what's different you can see if *that* is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you run the "Train your computer to better understand you" in the Control Panel-Speech Recognition?

Comment: @TomBrothers i think its nothing to do with speech recognition as i am using Microsoft.speech not System.speech.maybe the problem lies in the program reading the audio data. it doesn't work even for the commented line where i read data from .wav file.

Comment: @ChrisF thank you for replying, i said almost same because i dont know whats different. For me everything seems so obvious but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

i just replaced the Microsoft.Speech.Recognition to System.Speech.Recognition and it worked.

Don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling sre.RecognizeAsyncStop(); before it has a chance to recognise any speech. Remember async is non blocking, so it doesnt wait until speech is recognised. Remove that line and it should work.

Comment: i kept a Console.ReadLine(); statement so only when i give it some input the program proceeds so i think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a lower value into confidence. Maybe your microphone has too much noise or even muted? :)

Comment: i kept the microphone really close.
it was giving me almost 0.9 on my friends
i also debugged using  F11 and it works fine. I just dont understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your friend is running windows xp and you are running vista or 7. I think Microsoft actually included the speech recognition as part of the os package where in xp it wasn't. That could be a possible answer to why you had to change the include from Microsoft to System.